# Changing background color on UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone

How do I change the black/gray color to white?

This is just a simple view with a UIView attached to the UIViewControllers property together a with a webview that fills the UIView.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code that works:

```
- (void)loadView {
UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 416.0f)];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.view = webView;
[webview release];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: iPhone]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)'s backgroundColor property to achieve this, the signature being:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor
```

As such to change it to white, you'd use:

```
[myScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: @Andreas You should update your question - not put code in a comment. I've done this for you, so please delete your comment. :-)

Comment: The code still does not work, I don't know if it is correct to have a UIScrollView that contains a UIWebView since the UIWebView already scrolls, so maybe I must change the color somewhere in the UIWebView?

Comment: @Andreas - As the UIWebView is the same size as the UIScrollView I suspect this is the case - there's no value in having the UIScrollView there at all. (Might as well simply use a UIWebView.) That said, like the UIScrollView, the UIWebView inherits from UIView, so you should be able to set the background colo(u)r as above. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your time middaparka. Update my code and it is working as intended now:)

Comment: @Andreas - Cool. Happy programming. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A few improvements for your code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds)];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview: webView];
[webview release], webview = nil;
}
```

Overall you should find this approach less brittle.

PS. If you keep a reference to the `UIWebView` around, don't forget to release it in `- viewDidUnload`.

Comment: Releasing it in `-viewDidUnload` would result in an over-released web view, probably resulting in an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`—the correct approach would be to set the reference to `nil`. On the other hand, in your code above, setting `webview` to `nil` is useless: the variable gets discarded outside of the method's scope anyway.